# PHP boilerplate code?

Tags: php, html5boilerplate, boilerplate

I'm new to PHP.

I'm looking for some boilerplate code that that helps me get started on a new project, but not a complete framework. I'm thinking of something like the [**HTML5 Boilerplate**](https://html5boilerplate.com/), but for PHP.

I'd expect of such a boilerplate that it has some convenient ways to access a database, string manipulation, autoloading, etc.

Do you know any such **PHP Boilerplate**?

Comment: You mean something like a framework?

Comment: Accessing MySQL - maybe an ORM? Look at Propel or Doctrine, but be aware they're not suitable for absolute beginners, imo.

Comment: I guess he need a default php project structure with done MVC pattern or something.

Comment: I just want to template that includes class for sql CRUD operation, form validation, config and sort of things. I am reluctant to use orm because it is hard to optimize sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are some Template Engines like:

[Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/)
[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

when you need a PHP Framework there are some Frameworks. Google them a hint:

[Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/)
[Symfony2](http://symfony.com/)
[Cake PHP](http://cakephp.org/)

Comment: I do not think asker meant html templates engines, didn't he?

Comment: I think this is a better question then the main question :D i don't know what he need.

Comment: @Stony : He appears (or appeared, since this question is from 2012) to be looking for something like HTML5 Boilerplate, but for PHP. He used the word `template` as a reference for what's really known as `boilerplates` or `bootstraps`, so I "fixed" the question to reflect this!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to make your own template. I don't think developers will whare with others their templates. But if you don't want waste couple of hours for making a template, you always can use some of PHP frameworks, like Yii, codeigniter, kohana, ZFM, cake, etc. But they are not just a simple templates by the way.

Answer (score 1):

**php is a template engine itsself!**

don't use other template libraries, they just slow down the processing

**example**

```
<persons>
    <? foreach ($persons as $person): ?>
    <person>
        <firstname><?= $person>firstname ?></firstname>
        <lastname><?= $person->lastname ?></lastname>
    </person>
    <? endforeach; ?>
</persons>
```

**mysql**

there are several options like ORMs but for a beginner i would recommend to use PDO

Comment: Technically, it should be ($people as $person)

Comment: @VanNguyen lol that is just grammer ....lool

Comment: Persons is proper english too, it's just more formal than people :p

Answer (score 1):

You could try [CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/), [Kohana](https://kohanaframework.org/) or [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/).

While they ARE frameworks, they're pretty lightweight and all have the kind of features you're looking for.